# Encryption of results sent by SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, encryption

My client requires the communication between my web application and database server to be done in encrypted manner. Currently, they are converting the parameters into an encrypted XML and then pass this to web server.

My issues are:

1. I am still able to view the plain text (params and even the actual data) using SQL Trace
2. The results/table sent by the SQL Server stored procedure is in XML (plain). Is there any way to encrypt that communication as well?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if this will help you but i heard about CLR integration to SQL server where you can deploy c# dll to SQL server . So by this you can create an encryption/decryption logic in the c# and then deploy to SQL server. You can then use CLR stored procedure inside your SP for encryption This is just an idea but i am sure there must be other alternatives too :)

Comment: @PrashantKumar Hi, Thanks for the comment. But I am looking to encrypt the results sent from SQL Server to Web not for the encrypting the SP itself. Foreg. I want to encrypt the rows generated using "SELECT * FROM myTbl"

Comment: One Possible way (for issue no#2 mentioned in question) could be calling a encryption function for each and every column in select column but I am afraid that this will be unnecessarily hit speed of the execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server already has encrypted connections, use them. Read [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> **To configure SSL**
>
> - Install a certificate in the Windows certificate store of the server computer.
> - Click Start, in the Microsoft SQL Server program group, point to Configuration Tools, and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.
>     Expand SQL Server Network Configuration, right-click the protocols for the server you want, and then click Properties.
> - On the Certificate tab, configure the Database Engine to use the certificate.
> - On the Flags tab, view or specify the protocol encryption option. The login packet will always be encrypted.
>
> SQL Server must be restarted after you change the ForceEncryption setting.

Do **not** try to build your own broken in-house encryption attempt.

As for the trace visibility, this is a permission issue. Read [Permissions Required to Run SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187611.aspx). Only give the required permission to authorized users.

Comment: Many thanks @Remus. I got what I was looking for. One more doubt here related to Profiler. If I am able to see the data from Profiler, does this means that anybody who knows how to capture the data from Network, can see this(by means of hacking etc.)?

Comment: No. Network traffic is encrypted, is protected against any sort of hacking or capture. This includes Profiler network traffic.

Comment: Thanks Remus. Is there any other method/function/process by which we can implement our own encryption logic (in case the client does not want to go for SSL/incur additional costs )?

Comment: What is the 'additional cost'?

Comment: Price for getting SSL certificates.

Comment: You are not required to use a certificate signed by a trusted authority. You can use a self-signed certificate. Read [Using Encryption Without Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131691.aspx).